# Can fread be non rentrant?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, file

In a program written in C++ and compiled with MinGW-w64 under windows, I read several files concurrently in separate threads. Since the file names may have non ASCII characters, I cannot use the C++ standard library `std::ifstream` as it does not support `wchar` file names. So I need to use the C library with `_wfopen` from the Win32 API.

However, I get a very strange bug which I have reproduced in a MCVE. After reading n bytes with fread(), the result from `_ftelli64` is sometimes not increased by n, but by a few bytes less or more.

With single thread reading, the issue is gone, and with `std::ifstream` as well.

It acts as if there was a race condition in fread, which would then be non-reentrant.

In the following example, I replaced `_wfopen` by `fopen` as the bug is still there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

constexpr const int numThreads = 8;
constexpr const int blockSize = 65536+8;
constexpr const int fileBlockCount = 48; //3MB files

void readFile(const std::string & path)
{
    std::cout << "Reading file " << path << "\n";
    std::vector<char> buffer(blockSize);

    FILE * f = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
    for(int i=0;i<fileBlockCount;++i)
    {

        int64_t pos_before = _ftelli64(f);
        int64_t n = fread(buffer.data(), 1, buffer.size(),f);
        int64_t pos_after = _ftelli64(f);
        int64_t posMismatch = (int64_t)pos_after-(pos_before+n);
        if(ferror(f))
        {
            std::cout << "fread error\n";
        }
        if(posMismatch!=0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error " << path
                  << " / ftell before " << pos_before
                  << " / fread returned " << n
                  << " / ftell after " << pos_after
                  << " / mismatch " << posMismatch << "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
    //Generate file names
    std::vector<std::string> fileNames(numThreads);
    for(int i=0;i<numThreads;++i)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << i << ".dat";
        fileNames[i] = oss.str();
    }


    //Create dummy data files
    for(int i=0;i<numThreads;++i)
    {
        std::ofstream f(fileNames[i], std::ios_base::binary);
        for(int j=0;j<blockSize*fileBlockCount;++j)
        {
            f.put((char)(j&255));
        }
    }


    //Read data files in separate threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i=0;i<numThreads;++i)
    {
        threads.emplace_back(readFile, fileNames[i]);
    }

    //This waits for the threads to finish
    for(int i=0;i<numThreads;++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    threads.clear();

    std::cout << "Done";
}
```

The output is randomly something like:

```
Error 3.dat / ftell before 65544 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 131089 / mismatch 1
Error 7.dat / ftell before 0 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 65543 / mismatch -1
Error 7.dat / ftell before 65543 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 131088 / mismatch 1
Error 3.dat / ftell before 2162953 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 2228498 / mismatch 1
Error 7.dat / ftell before 2162952 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 2228497 / mismatch 1
Error 3.dat / ftell before 3080570 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 3146112 / mismatch -2
Error 7.dat / ftell before 3080569 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 3146112 / mismatch -1
Error 2.dat / ftell before 65544 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 131089 / mismatch 1
Error 6.dat / ftell before 0 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 65543 / mismatch -1
Error 6.dat / ftell before 65543 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 131088 / mismatch 1
Error 2.dat / ftell before 2162953 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 2228498 / mismatch 1
Error 6.dat / ftell before 2162952 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 2228497 / mismatch 1
Error 2.dat / ftell before 3080570 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 3146112 / mismatch -2
Error 6.dat / ftell before 3080569 / fread returned 65544 / ftell after 3146112 / mismatch -1
```

***EDIT : This seems related to `_ftelli64`***

If I replace `_ftelli64` by `ftell`, the issue is not there anymore
So is this a broken not reentrent implementation of `_ftelli64` ?

Comment: Well, obviously `fread()` *can* be non-reentrant.  I guess the question is whether it *is* non-reentrant on Win32, and perhaps whether that would be conforming.

Comment: According to microsoft (look at remarks in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx ) the return value from `ftell()` or (as you're using) `_ftelli64()`  is determined by the last I/O operation.  They wouldn't have made that sort of remark unless there was potential for some mismatch, such as what you have seen.

Comment: @Peter, those comments seem to be directed mainly at files opened in append mode, where the next write will always occur at the end of the file, which may not be immediately following the last read.

Comment: Those deviations don't look like race conditions to me. They look like error returns being misinterpreted as byte counts. Try logging more information about mismatches. (Starting position, bytes reported read, reported ending position, filename.)

Comment: @rici : I updated the example and typical output

Comment: `ferror` never reports any error even when there is a mismatch. Besides this 1)I'm reading from hdd not from a faulty IO source 2)This happens on all systems I have tested so this is not due to the hardware/system 3)It does not happen with 1 thread 4)It does not happen with std::iostream => To me this is a race condition

Comment: Unicode filenames work like a charm in fstreams under cygwin g++.

Comment: @galinette: Thanks, that seems like useful information.

Comment: @n.m. you mean that std::fstream has a wstring constructor? I'd like a proof of this...

Comment: No, it works with narrow strings (converts to and from utf8?)

Comment: @galinette: ok, i'm convinced that it is not related to an error return. The regularity of your test output, however, leads me to still be a bit skeptical about the race condition theory, although it is of course possible. But there are many other possibilities. One question I have is whether your _ftelli64 is really calling that msvcrt function, or whether it might be using `_telli64(fileno(f))` instead, which I believe has slightly different semantics.

Comment: Windows systems do `fopen` in text mode by eliminating CRLF sequences and converting them into `\n` chars.... this can lead to reading some chars less or more than you expect, if you have this sequences in a binary file that's being read in text mode.  Be careful and check you didn't `fopen` in text mode.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're asking mostly about the C standard library, the C standard says:

> Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.
>
> All functions that read, write, position, or query the position of a stream lock the stream before accessing it. They release the lock associated with the stream when the access is complete.

([C2011 7.21.2/7-8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p7))

C++ folks should note that in C, "stream" means the kind of thing accessed via a `FILE *`.  Of `fread()`, the standard says, in part,

> The file position indicator for the stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters successfully read.

and

> The fread function returns the number of elements successfully read

but also

> If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file position indicator for the stream is indeterminate.

([C2011, 7.21.8.1/2-3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.1p2))

It seems not to characterize reaching the end of the stream as an error.

Although C11 does not specifically say that `fread()` must be thread-safe, it does acknowledge the existence of multithreaded programs and define their semantics.  It specifies that in such programs,

> The execution of each thread proceeds as defined by the remainder of this standard.

([C2011, 5.1.2.4/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p1))

That does not afford the possibility of `fread()` failing to behave as documented when called in parallel on different streams, and the locking requirements I cited earlier prevent data races and the attending undefined behavior even when it is called in parallel on *the same* stream.

`_ftelli64()` is not a standard library function in ISO C, but the Win32 docs specify its behavior in the same terms that that they specify the behavior of `ftell()`, which *is* a standard library function.  Both

> retrieve the current position of the file pointer (if any) associated with `stream`. The position is expressed as an offset relative to the beginning of the stream.

([Microsoft C library documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64))

Microsoft's "file pointer" is the same thing as ISO C's "file position".  Overall, then, the only way I can see the observed behavior conforming is if a few of the `fread()` calls encounter errors.  You can check for this by calling `ferror()` in the event that `fread()` returns 0.  If there are errors, then all bets are off.

Comment: fread always returns the number of bytes I have asked. ferror always returns 0 (no error)

Comment: Well then, @galinette, unless two of your threads are reading from the same file, you are observing a bug in Microsoft's C library.  Do note that multiple threads reading the same file really could produce the results you describe, though.  Two different threads' `fread()` calls on the same file could occasionally occur between between the `_ftelli64()` calls of one or both threads, producing the behavior you observe.  That would be consistent with the fact that the differences you observe appear to balance out to zero on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: Rather a bug from MinGW dll. One of the MinGW developpers told me that _ftelli64 is not exported by msvcrt.dll, so they reimplemented it (and possibly broke it)

Comment: @galinette, in that event, yes, it is plausible that the bug is in MinGW rather than in msvcrt.  I'm not sure how one would prove it, but I'm also not sure it matters which one is to blame.  Anyway, the bottom line remains that the behavior you observe does not conform to the requirements of the standard.

Comment: @john: but that code does not read from the same  `FILE` in two different threads. It doesn't even read from the same file in two threads. Also: `_ftelli64` does not form part of any standard and according to OP, there is no problem when the standard `ftell` is used.

Comment: @rici, if the problem is indeed in `_ftelli64()` then you're right.  Although the fact that the problem is not observed when `ftell()` is used instead is suggestive that this is the case, it is not definitive.  Anyway, I don't really care in which function the problem lies.  The bottom line -- as I should have said it -- is that the observed joint behavior of the two functions does not conform to the functions' respective specifications.